# How are MFCC extracted in pysptk library?

Tags: python, math, speech-recognition, speech, mfcc

The algorithm for MFCC extraction is:

1. Compute the Fourier transform of (a windowed excerpt of) a signal.
2. Map the powers of the spectrum obtained above onto the mel scale, using triangular overlapping windows.
3. Take the logs of the powers at each of the mel frequencies.
4. Take the discrete cosine transform of the list of mel log powers, as if it were a signal.

Here is the code from pysptk library.

```
def sp2mc(powerspec, order, alpha):

    """Convert spectrum envelope to mel-cepstrum

    This is a simplified implementation of "mcep" for input type
    is 4.

    Parameters
    ----------
    powerspec : array
        Power spectrum

    order : int
        Order of mel-cepstrum

    alpha : float
        All-pass constant.

    Returns
    -------
    mc : array, shape(``order+1``)
        mel-cepstrum

    See Also
    --------
    pysptk.sptk.mcep
    pysptk.conversion.mc2sp

    """

    # |X(ω)|² -> log(|X(ω)²|)
    logperiodogram = np.log(powerspec)

    # transform log-periodogram to real cepstrum
    # log(|X(ω)|²) -> c(m)
    c = np.fft.irfft(logperiodogram)
    c[0] /= 2.0

    # c(m) -> cₐ(m)
    return freqt(c, order, alpha)
```

It takes as an input the power spectrum, so step 1 is already done.

Then it takes logarithm, skipping step 2?

Then it does the np.fft.irfft transformation - I'm guessing it acts like dct on certain inputs? On "inputs type 4" (what does that mean, by the way)? Is that right?

In the end, it does the "frequency transformation" (freqt) - what does it do?

Is it a different algorithm? How does it work? At what stage is the signal mapped onto the mel scale?

Comment: Maybe `powerspec` is assumed to be Mel-scaled filtered already?

Comment: I think not, because throughout the documentation, sp or powerspec refers to power spectrum. E.g. there's a reverse mc2sp function, and the shape of the output is fftlen//2 +1, as it should be in power spectrum. And these functions actually reverse each other.

Comment: Looks like it's indeed a different algorithm